# How to make auto increment number on my table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make auto increment number on my table

The table load data from ajax request with jquery like this

```
function loadData(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "../myCrud/display.php",             
      dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
      success: function(result){                    
        var resObj = JSON.parse(result);
        var dataHandler = $("#loader");
        $.each(resObj,function(key,val){
          i = 1;
          for();
          var newRow = `<tr><td>${i}</td><td>${val.id}</td><td>${val.product_name}</td><td>${val.stock}</td><td>${val.price}</td><td>${val.product_desc}</td><td>${val.sold}</td><td>${val.img}</td></tr>`
          dataHandler.append(newRow);
        })
      }
    })
}
```

and this is my html code :

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Product Id</th>
      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th>Stock</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Product Description</th>
      <th>Sold</th>
      <th>Image</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="loader">

  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want the number at "#" column is auto.

Answer (score 1):

In your post, you only declare `i` in inside the loop and it is not incremented, so put `i` outside loop and increment it inside loop. Try like below.

```
function loadData(){
$.ajax({
  type: "post",
  url: "../myCrud/display.php",             
  dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
  success: function(result){                    
    var resObj = JSON.parse(result);
    var dataHandler = $("#loader");
    var i = 1;
    $.each(resObj,function(key,val){
      i = i++;
      for();
      var newRow = `<tr><td>${i}</td><td>${val.id}</td><td>${val.product_name}</td><td>${val.stock}</td><td>${val.price}</td><td>${val.product_desc}</td><td>${val.sold}</td><td>${val.img}</td></tr>`
      dataHandler.append(newRow);
    })
  }
})
}
```

Comment: i= i++ could just be i++, no need for the i=, also what does for() do here??

Comment: @Rmaxx yeah, `i++` only is good. I just copy paste the OP question.. remember that

Answer (score -1):

```js
function loadData(){
    let i = 1;
    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "../myCrud/display.php",             
      dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
      success: function(result){                    
        var resObj = JSON.parse(result);
        var dataHandler = $("#loader");
        $.each(resObj,function(key,val){
          i = i+1;
          for();
          var newRow = `<tr><td>${i}</td><td>${val.id}</td><td>${val.product_name}</td><td>${val.stock}</td><td>${val.price}</td><td>${val.product_desc}</td><td>${val.sold}</td><td>${val.img}</td></tr>`
          dataHandler.append(newRow);
        })
      }
    })
}
```